# Recursive method for Amicable numbers between 1 - 10000 Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem with creating a recursive method for finding Amicable numbers between 1 - 10000. I created a method to find out if two numbers are Amicable, but I don't know how to run it against every possible number combination. Here are both methods which I wrote.

```
public void amicable(int n, int m) {
    int sumM = 0;
    int sumN = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            sumN += i;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
        if (m % j == 0) {
            sumM += j;
        }
    }

    if (sumN == m && sumM == n) {
        System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are amicable numbers");
    }
}

public static void amicableBetween(int n, int m) {
    int sumaM = 0;
    int sumaN = 0;
    if (m >= 1) {

        for (int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
            if (m % j == 0) {
                sumaM += j;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                sumaN += i;
            }
        }

        if (sumaN == m && sumaM == n) {
            System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are amicable numbers");
            amicableBetween(n + 1, m - 1);
        } else {
            System.out.println(n + " i " + m + " aren't amicable numbers");
            amicableBetween(n + 1, m - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Your question is missing a clear problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Minor disclaimer, this method might take forever and you might run out of stack space so I'm not 100% sure that calculating all the amicable numbers from 1-10000 recursively is the way to go. If this is just for fun or practice then I guess is ok.

---

One approach will be to sweep `n` until we reach `m - 1` and call `amicable(n,m)` in each step. Once `n` has reached `m - 1`, we can decrease `m` by `1` and repeat the process until `n is equal to m - 1` then we have checked all possible combinations. To do this, you can break your two methods into three methods.

The first method is the `amicable` method you already have, just changed the return type so that we can reuse it while we are going down the recursion chain:

```
public static boolean amicable(int n, int m) {
    int sumM = 0;
    int sumN = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            sumN += i;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < m; j++) {
        if (m % j == 0) {
            sumM += j;
        }
    }

    return sumN == m && sumM == n;
}
```

The second will be the `public` method `amicableBetween(int n, int m)`

```
public static void amicableBetween(int n, int m) {

    amicableBetween(n, m, true);
}
```

Which will call a third `private` helper method `amicableBetween(int n, int m, boolean start)` that has a third parameter `start` that it can use to identify if `n` has reached `m`. Then we need to decrease `m` by `1` and repeat the process:

```
private static void amicableBetween(int n, int m, boolean start) {

    if(n == m) {
        return;
    }

    if (m >= 1) {

        if (amicable(n, m)) {
            System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " are amicable numbers");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n + " and " + m + " aren't amicable numbers");
        }
        amicableBetween(n + 1, m, false);
    }
    if(start) {
        amicableBetween(n, m - 1, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I need , but taking too long and sometimes getting stackoverflow. But anyway thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why do you want a *recursive* algorithm. Don't you warry about *StackOvervlowException*?! It is pretty easy to find with simple `Map` within `O(n)` time:

```
public static void amicable(int lo, int hi) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = lo; i <= hi; i++) {
        int j = map.computeIfAbsent(i, DIV_SUM);

        if (j > i && j <= hi && map.computeIfAbsent(j, DIV_SUM) == i)
            System.out.format("[%d : %d]\n", i, j);
    }
}

private static final Function<Integer, Integer> DIV_SUM = val -> {
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1, max = val / 2; i <= max; i++)
        if (val % i == 0)
            sum += i;

    return sum;
};
```

*Demo: time ~150ms*

```
amicable(1, 10000);

[220 : 284]
[1184 : 1210]
[2620 : 2924]
[5020 : 5564]
[6232 : 6368]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is fastest solution which I found. But still without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

So, you wrote a method that can tell if two numbers are amicable. That's the hard part out of the way. All you have to do is call that from inside two loops, one for the upper bound, one for the lower bound.

```
for(lowerNumber = 1; lowerNumber < 10000; lowerNumber++){
    for(upperNumber = lowerNumber + 1; upperNumber <= 10000; upperNumber++){
        amicable(lowerNumber, upperNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this , but I can't use it in recursive method (getting StackOverflowError ). And the most important thing for this example is to do it with recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need two parameters in the `amicable` function. An amicable number has a repeating aliquot sequence of period 2, which means

```
s(s(n)) == n
```

We can find the number's complement by retrieving the sum of its proper divisors and checking the assertion above.

This means to find the amicable numbers for `n` between 1 and 10,000 we only need `n`, and would also make trivial the part of the process you seem to want as a recursion.

JavaScript code:

```js
function s(n){
  let s = n > 1 ? 1 : 0;
  let sqrt_n = Math.sqrt(n);
  let d1=Math.floor(n/2);
  
  for (; d1>=sqrt_n; d1--){
    let d2 = n / d1;
    
    if (d2 == Math.floor(d2))
      s += d1 + d2;
  }
    
  if (d1 == sqrt_n)
    s += d1;
    
  return s;
}

let n = 220;
let s_n = s(n);

if (s(s_n) == n)
  console.log('Amicable!', n, s_n);
```